# Use LINQ to select a string from file, split it, and return specified members

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file-io, lambda

I have a very big file (> 1GB) which is pipe delimited.
I want to query the file using file.readlines, split each line, select specific elements from the splited line, according to index list (I will provide the array of indexes) and return it to a dictionary of custom type class object.

Currently I have this:

```
strIndexes = "1,3,5,7";
var selected = strIndexes.Split(',')
                         .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                         .Select(index => File.readlines(myFile)
                         .Select(x => split('|')[index]).toArray();
```

However this query is led by the index and is not that efficient. 
It returns 4 vectors, each one for the specified 4 index in the example above.

I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for commenting.
I'm adding some sample data.
File data looks like this:

```
Line1: aa|ab|de|gt|hj|de|fr|gt|hy // Header
Line2: sd|12|f4|tr|hj|df|ds|e3|12
Line3: 34|fd|3d|35|df|45|dq|32|dd
.
.
.
Line N 34|df|f3|df|33|s2|23|df|44
```

N = millions of lines.
The data format is just for purpose of the example, each cell holds a string of different length and structure.

Now, the user enters the requested data he wants in form of header column names, let's say for example: ab,de,fr,hy, I parse this and understand I need columns 2,3, 7 and 9.
Now I want to parse the file and return an object where each entry is a dictionary entry, that represents a data in a line, which holds a key (which is one of the columns data) and a value which is a string[] of the tokenized data.

So let's say for this example I want the data to be sorted by column number 7, so the final dict would be:

```
[ds]->[12,f4,12]
[dq]->[fd,3d,dd]
.
.
.
[23]->[df,f3,44]
```

Comment: For one thing, I would avoid reading the file each time for each index.

Comment: It's quite hard to follow what you're trying to achieve. If you could give sample input and desired output, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @Xander: I correctly cased `ReadLines` and `.ToArray()` and moved the `.ToArray()` call to the next line to match the rest of the statement. What changed semantically?

Comment: @Lee I think the OP's problem is exactly that - he wants to avoid re-reading the file and is looking for a more efficient approach.

Comment: @Xander: Nice catch - lining up the nested `.Select` on the same line is an odd choice (mixed with the now-missing final parenthesis). Rolled back.

Comment: Not sure that I undestand what you want, follow the @JonSkeet's comment and provide some input and desired output, so we can think about it.

Comment: Specifying the technology to solve an arbitrary problem rather than asking for the best technology to solve the problem is like asking an oven to cool your beer in the most efficient way.

Comment: Correct if i'm wrong: the result you expect is a dictionary that has one entry for each index and as value the tokens in the file? Like this `Dictionary<int, string[]>`? Take a look at my answer and comment there what is not corresponding with what you want, then we try to advance. But definitly  Linq is not a good solution, you'll have to parse the file in another way.

Comment: and he will never come back to see the answers...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing your own tokenizer (or find one), you can use [String.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wh7x3fs) and search for either '|' or ',', build your own state machine to tell it where to plop these values.

Answer (score 0):

Some guessing, but maybe this is what you want to do:

```
// Split indexes string to integers
var indexes = strIndexes.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

// Read file once
var lines = File.ReadLines(myFile);

// Split them (thank you, devundef!)
var splitLines = lines.Select(line => line.Split('|')).ToArray();

// Create dictionary index => column array
var dict = indexes.ToDictionary(
        index => index,
        index => splitLines.Select(splitLine => splitLine[index]).ToArray()
    );
```

Comment: There is place for more one optimization: do the split outside with `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: I was thinking in something like this: `var lines = File.ReadLines(myFile).Select(line => line.Split('|')).ToArray();`, so you enumerate the lines just once and use half of memory. Sorry  for stick my nose on your answer :)

Comment: ReadLines returns an array... unfortunately, there is no memory to be saved ... oh it doesn't, confusing it with ReadAllLines!

Answer (score 0):

First, parse your index string (strIndex) outside of the query to avoid repeating that step multiple times:

```
string strIndexes = "7,2,3,9";
int[] indexes = Array.ConvertAll(strIndexes.Split(','), e => int.Parse(e) - 1);
```

Note that I've placed the 7 first, because assuming that the first index is your key index simplifies the needed code. I also noticed that your indexes appear to be 1-based in the string, which is why I subtract 1 to create a 0-based array of indexes. Then this yields a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` of the form you requested:

```
var selected = (from line in File.ReadLines(myFile)
                let lineArray = line.Split('|')
                select (from index in indexes
                select lineArray[index]))
               .ToDictionary(key => key.First(), value => value.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Running this against your 4 lines of sample data yields:

```
[fr]->[ab, de, hy]
[ds]->[12, f4, 12]
[dq]->[fd, 3d, dd]
[23]->[df, f3, 44]
```

from this code:

```
foreach (var item in selected)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]->[{1}]", item.Key, string.Join(", ", item.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked for a linq solution, I think maybe this is not a good practice because your files are large and you'll allocate a lot of memory for a single task or even get a OutOfMemoryException.

You can just parse each line of the file once and extract the values for each index:

```
public Dictionary<int, List<String>> ParseFile(String fileName, int[] indexes)
    var file = File.OpenText(myFile);
    var dict = indexes.ToDictionary(i => i, i => new List<string>());

    while(!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = file.ReadLine().Split('|');
        foreach(var entry in dict)
            entry.Value.Add(line[entry.Key]);
    }
    file.Dispose();
    return dict;
}
```